# how to check SSL certificate expiration date programmatically in Java

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient, ssl-certificate

I need to extract expiration date from SSL certificate on web site in Java,should support both 
trusted and self-signed certificate,such as:
1.trusted
https://github.com
2.self-signed
https://mms.nw.ru/

I already copy some code as:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class SSLTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        // configure the SSLContext with a TrustManager
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        URL url = new URL("https://github.com");//https://mms.nw.ru
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
        for (Certificate cert :certs){
            System.out.println(cert.getType());
            System.out.println(cert);
        }

        conn.disconnect();
    }

    private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The questions are:

1. How to parse the expiration date from the certificate, in my code the toString() did output the date,but it is hard to parse.
2. How to determine the certificate chain, eg, the github certificate with chains 3, how did i know which certificate to get the expiration date from?

Comment: Google is directing here even though I'm asking for .NET, so I'll just add [this link](http://forums.asp.net/post/4630222.aspx) to a C# answer.

Comment: I had to add `conn.connect();` before the for-loop to get this code to work and stop receiving `java.lang.IllegalStateException: connection not yet open`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> How to parse the expiration date from the certificate

Cast it to an `X509Certificate` and call `getNotAfter()`.

> How to determine the certificate chain, eg, the github certificate with chains

You've got it. That's what the `Certificate[]` array is, as it says in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getServerCertificates()).

> How did i know which certificate to get the expiration date from?

Read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getServerCertificates()). "The peer's own certificate first followed by any certificate authorities".

However I don't know why you're doing any of this. Java should already do it all for you.

And please throw away that insecure and incorrect TrustManager implementation. The correct way to handle self-signed certificates is to import them into the client truststore. Please also throw away your insecure HostnameVerifier, and use the default one, or a secure one. Why use HTTPS at all if you don't want it to be secure?

Comment: my application is an monitoring tool which has a function to monitor the SSL expiration date so that customer could be notified when it will expire soon. So i do not care whether the HTTPS is sucure, i just care when it will expire. what do you mean by "Java should already do it all for you."?

Comment: @Grace I meant that if the certificate(s) have expired it will throw an `SSLHandshakeException`. It's hard to believe that a simple calendar entry wouldn't accomplish the purpose without writing any Java code at all.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. It's OK for me to cast from Certificate to X509Certificate. Anyway our programs aim to automatically monitor the expiration date of one certificate and will notify admin if it will expire soon.Our application is a monitoring system just like nagios etc.That's it. You did help very much:)

Comment: @Grace I see, have fun with it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you append Begin/End lines to PEM format otherwise java does not understand it.

```
public class CertTest {

    public static final String cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n<CERT_DATA>\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            X509Certificate myCert = (X509Certificate)CertificateFactory
                     .getInstance("X509")
                     .generateCertificate(
                                       // string encoded with default charset
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.getBytes())
                     );
            System.out.println(myCert.getNotAfter());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest that Java didn't understand the certificate format.

Comment: This actually helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin way, it should look something like this:

```
fun certInformation(aURL: String) {
    val destinationURL = URL(aURL)
    val conn = destinationURL.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
    conn.connect()
    val certs = conn.serverCertificates
    for (cert in certs) {
        println("Certificate is: $cert")
        if (cert is X509Certificate) {
            println(cert.issuerDN.name)
            println(cert.notAfter)
            println(cert.notBefore)
        }
    }
}
```